# Asp.net URL rewriting - Querystring gets images, css and js file

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have created a web site in which i am trying to implement url rewriting. When I clicked on anchor tag it success fully post the value to other page. I have captured the value in Request.Querystring in other form. But it also captures the images, js and cs files located on the other page in query string.

As shown in below screenshot,the query string shows the value as main.css

[image]

Please help

**Main File**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/home/My-Home-Page">
    Home Page
</asp:LinkButton>
```

**Redirect File**

```
if (Request.QueryString["variant"] != null || Request.QueryString["variant"] != "")
{
}
```

**Webconfig**

```
<rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/home/(.+)" to="~/Product-Details.aspx?variant=$1" />
</rewriter>

<httpModules>
    <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
</httpModules>

<configSections>
    <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
</configSections>
```

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani updated.